# IOS iframe width jumps back on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically i have a iframe embedded from a non responsive site, in a container div that allows it to be scrollable on mobile.

```
 <div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto; overflow-y: auto; -webkit-overflow-   scrolling: touch; height: 7000px; position: relative;">
 <iframe style="background: transparent; height: 100%; width: 100%;" frameborder="0" src="https://myurl"></iframe>
 </div>
```

This works fine for most pages in the iframe, however on one page with a table with a large width, the horizontal scrolling jumps back when you reach the end of the table horizontally.

Unfortunately i can't give out links for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

And what if you use the Overflow attribute?

```
overflow: hidden
```

hides all overflow (if used correctly). You can also use

```
overflow-x: hidden
overflow-y: hidden
```

Comment: The overflow needs to be viewable unfortunately. i need to use some sort of scrolling method